# Erlang: net_adm:names() returns {error, nxdomain}

Tags: erlang

When executing net_adm:names(), I get an error {error, nxdomain}. nxdomain implies the domain name does not exist, but I am able to ping my host name in the terminal and successfully ping between Erlang nodes started on different terminals. As such, I'm not sure how to fix this one?

Thanks.

Comment: Try starting both nodes with -sname. That doesn't require a valid hostname.

Answer (score 1):

```
net_adm:names()
```

defaults to local host, which is obtained via

```
net_adm:localhost()
```

This in turn uses those two functions:

```
inet:gethostname().
net_db:res_option(domain).
```

And this info is obtained from the system, so check what is returned by

```
hostname
cat /etc/resolv.conf #or something else depending on OS
```

Your operating system might report wrong domain to Erlang, so you are able to ping it when typing the domain by hand, but not when using the domain obtained from net_db:res_option(domain). Editing /etc/resolv.conf should fix your problem.